# Does CoffeeScript support interpolation in single quotation string?

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

I come to this question:

```
 f = (param) ->
      console.info '#{param}'
 f(1)
```

The outcome is `#{param}`

When I enclose the string with double quotation marks, this just print `1`. I have also tested it in Ruby, its behaviour is the same. But that just contradicts the rule in CoffeeScript.org:

**The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript".**

Because I think in Javascript, single quotes and double quotes are treated equally. And I do not use Ruby often. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's only a golden rule in that it ends *up* being JavaScript, that doesn't mean it acts list JavaScript at the CoffeeScript source level. There's magic all over the place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"It's just javascript" means it fundamentally compiles to ordinary JavaScript and doesn't attempt to take a radically different programming paradigm and compile it to JavaScript. CoffeeScript is primarily concerned with avoiding "the bad parts", boilerplate, and unnecessary syntax as opposed to introducing radically different basic constructs such as data types, etc.

JavaScript has no string interpolation. CoffeeScript brings this over from Ruby as a convenience. Disabling it for single quotes just gives you a clean way to get a string without the interpolation interpreted.

Don't take **It's just JavaScript** to mean **It IS JavaScript**. It's a flavor/variant/sibling.

Comment: Unlike ruby interpolation of a string (double-quotes) vs literal strings (single-quote) *compile* to JavaScript as a string. Therefore there is no *runtime* overhead. There maybe a compile time overhead. However, as in ruby the performance difference is so negligible that the use of single vs double is more personal style / preference then performance.

Comment: "JavaScript has no string interpolation". It finally does in es6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals :)

Answer (score 15):

From the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org):

> Ruby-style string interpolation is included in CoffeeScript.
>   Double-quoted strings allow for interpolated values, using #{ ... },
>   and single-quoted strings are literal.

Comment: Except that single-quoted strings are *not* really literal as they are in Ruby.  In Javascript, single quoted strings act like double quoted strings and interpret and treat the backslash as an escape character for \n, etc, requiring actual backslashes to be escaped. Coffeescript perpetuates this behavior for reasons that are not clear to me.